# Converting a apriori object to a list taking more time even for small number of data

Tags: machine-learning, apriori

I am working on a data set of more than 22,000 records, and when I tried it with the apriori model, it's taking way too much time even for small number of records like 20. Is there a problem in my code or Is there a faster way to convert the asscocians into a list quickly? The code I used is below.

```
for i in range(0, 20):
    transactions.append([str(dataset.values[i,j]) for j in range(0, 543)])

from apyori import apriori
associations = apriori(transactions, min_support=0.004, min_confidence=0.3, min_lift=3, min_length=2)
result = list(associations)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to assess without your data, but the complexity of Apriori is based on a number of factors, including your support threshold, number of transactions, number of items, average/max transaction length, etc.

In cases where even a small number of transactions is taking a long time to run it's often a matter of too low of a minimum support. When support is very low (near 0) the algorithm is effectively still brute forcing, since it has to look at all possible combinations of items, of every length. This is the equivalent of a [mathematical power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), which is exponential. For just 41 items you're actually trying 2^41 -1 possible combinations, which is **just over 1.1 TRILLION possibilities**.

I recommend starting with a "high" min_support at first (e.g. 0.20) and then working your way down slowly. It's easier to test things that take seconds at first than ones that'll take a long time.

Other important note: There is no min_length parameter in Apyori. I'm not sure where everyone's getting that from (you're not alone in thinking there is one), unless it's this one random blog post I found. The parameters are as follows (straight from [the code](https://github.com/ymoch/apyori/blob/master/apyori.py)):

```
Keyword arguments:
    min_support -- The minimum support of relations (float).
    min_confidence -- The minimum confidence of relations (float).
    min_lift -- The minimum lift of relations (float).
    max_length -- The maximum length of the relation (integer).
```

For what it's worth, I wrote unofficial docs for Apyori that can be found [here](http://www.zaxrosenberg.com/unofficial-apyori-documentation/).

Comment: Hi, some where I have seen using min_length as a parameter, is min_length parameter is there in above implementation? 
I am working on a problem , where I have to predict two new items from 1 item, can above algorithm be used to build that?